What is the number in parenthesis after a Windows 11 Task Manager process?
What is the number in parenthesis after a Windows 11 Task Manager process?


This question is similar to: What does this numbers in bracket mean?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

That is the number of processes running within that application. Just hit the > expand symbol to view all those processes.
